Snowdrop Install started uninstalling my system. How can I revover?
I tried to install a piece of software called "snowdrop" via the "apt install" command. Specifically, "apt install -y snowdrop.
As usual, the installation starts. Everything seems fine initially, but then I start seeing lines of "removing this", "removing that", "removing the other".
Before I can react, half the software on my system is gone, including networkmanager. I stopped the command.
I hopped onto a second laptop and grabbed the deb file for networkmanager, slapped it onto a USB stick, hopped back to the screwed up system and tried "dpkg -i networkmanager" (obviously in the correct folder, using the deb filename, etc). dpkg gives me an error of some kind, which I'll dig up and add in an edit shortly.
So I currently have qterminal available, access to the filesystem, a USB stick I can use, and dpkg, but can't connect to any networks.
Can I recover from this, or will a file backup and a fresh install be the better option?
EDIT: System backed up, I'm reinstalling.

Which linux distro are you on? Since this doesn't happen to me, I can't write an answer that actually solves your issue, I can just give you pointers.

Do you have packages in /var/cache/apt/archives?

I'm on Kali. If uname was still working, I'd tell you which version, but sod knows. I've been running it for years, mostly for monitoring and protecting my network. I've uninstalled and installed loads of things over the years, but I've never run across an issue like this. I'm blacklisting snowdrop on my systems going forward.

@Lee I think you might have missed my question about — do you have packages in /var/cache/apt/archives?

Apologies for the slow response. Addressing everyone's points - kali 6.6.9, there are plenty of packages in the apt archives, sorry about the tagging issues but I was stressed and not thinking straight at the time of asking this question. If I've missed anything, let me know

apt install -y snowdrop means "Install the snowdrop package, and assume "yes" for any question I might want to ask you". I would strongly recommend you don't use -y in the future

Yh, I agree with you there Chris. Steering clear of it in future.

It’s too late now of course, but there’s a high probability you could have restored the removed packages from /var/cache/apt/archives.

@StephenKitt Could I ask you to explain how, for future reference?

First of all, on my system, installing snowdrop does not uninstall networkmanager. So, I suspect you're either using an "esoteric" non-debian distro (mx? kali?), and well, uff, that exposes you to such risks, or you're using a third-party repository that contains a version of snowdrop incompatible with your version of debian.
Acting as if you're using plain debian (as commented, you're probably not doing that, but this is the best I can guess):
You should prepare a debian live USB image and boot from that. Mount your root filesystem somethere, e.g. as /target.
Then, you can use the functioning networking to undo the last operation. Let's hope your dpkg experiments didn't bring additional breakage! So, let's hope that your system's apt-get is still functional, you'd do something like:

mount your root file system at some prefix, say "PREFIX=/target"
Make a backup of your data. This is also the point where, looking at your backup, you might decide to screw steps 3.–end and just reinstall debian, and copy the backup of your data in afterwards.
bind-mount /proc, /sys and /dev under "$PREFIX"
copy your /etc/resolv.conf to $PREFIX/etc/resolv.conf for the time being
open $TARGET/var/log/dpkg.log to see what was uninstalled
chroot $TARGET and use apt to reinstall that (don't do funny things with dpkg manually)
reboot

EDIT So you're on Kali and try to use that for picture waterprinting. Wrong platform. Use a general-purpose debian, not a special covert pentesting tool. Don't fix or reinstall Kali just to use it for something it's not meant to do.

So short answer: you're recommending a backup and reinstall?

Read my answer in full, please.
